# npm ci fails with ProcessTerminatedError in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, openshift

**npm ci** is failing in the docker container. below are the error details

```
[15:58:27][Step 2/2] npm verb teardown shutting down workers.
[15:58:33][Step 2/2] npm info teardown Done in 0.299s
[15:58:35][Step 2/2] npm verb type ProcessTerminatedError
[15:58:35][Step 2/2] npm verb stack ProcessTerminatedError: cancel after 1 retries!
[15:58:35][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at Farm.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:87:25)
[15:58:35][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
[15:58:35][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at Farm.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:81:36)
[15:58:35][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
[15:58:36][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
[15:58:55][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
[15:59:13][Step 2/2] npm verb stack     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

so looks like npm uses the `worker-farm` lib underneath to achieve the `npm ci`.

I'm doing this in the `openshift` environment. when I allocate `2Gi` size limit the `npm ci` works fine but with `1Gi` the above error is produced. my app is very small (`node_modules` is around `20 MB` on my local machine) and from the pods I can see the total size is under `200MB` in `openshift`.

any idea why this is happening in the Docker container with reduced size limit (I recon it's race condition as after long wait I get out of memory)? what can we do to get rid of this problem if we necessarily want to do the `npm ci` inside the docker.